# Natural language processing tags

Tags: discussion, tags

Which of the following tags you can suggest to merge or remove?

- [nlp](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nlp)
- [computational-linguistics](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/computational-linguistics)
- <s>[natural-language](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/natural-language)</s> (deleted)
- [lexical-recognition](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lexical-recognition)
- <s>[language-processing](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/language-processing)</s> (deleted)
- [grammar-induction](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grammar-induction)
- <s>[pattern-languages](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pattern-languages)</s> (deleted)

And which one should be a synonym of another term? Basically, what should be the main tags for natural language processing? [nlp](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nlp)?

Answer (score 1):

**[natural-language](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/natural-language) should stay. The others - synonymize.**

[natural-language](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/natural-language) is the most descriptive tag name, as a person who knows fairly close to nothing about AI. If you add the others as synonyms, then everyone will be able to find the right tag. :)

Comment: Tags are not meant to facilitate newbies (AFAIK), but to organise the community.