# Rename [nlp] to [natural-language-processing]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retagging

Currently, we have the tag [nlp](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nlp). Now that we have 35 characters in tags, can we change this to [natural-language-processing](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/natural-language-processing)?

Comment: Hmm, I also notice a [`natural-language`](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/natural-language) tag with some overlap. Should anything be done involving that tag?

Comment: @Ben - that may be worth its own meta post

Comment: @BenN I saw 2 tags language processing and nlp..aren't the two synonyms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is done now, sorry for the delay.

We still have [natural-language](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/natural-language) and [language-processing](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/language-processing), which sound pretty similar to [natural-language-processing](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/natural-language-processing) — it might be worth revisiting [this NLP tag discussion](https://ai.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1182/75).